# Mathematical notation for fractions in lowest terms

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

I'm looking for standard mathematical notation that deals with fractions in lowest terms.

Specifically, I'm looking for a way to express the minimum of the fraction's numerator or denominator. For example, $8/9$ and $9/8$ should both return $8$. How should one write this as part of an equation?

Comment: I don't think there is any standard notation for fractions in lowest terms. Authors generally just [state the result is in lowest terms](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C16&q=fraction+%22in+lowest+terms%22) (or some equivalent, such as GCD of the numerator and denominator is 1).
 As for a function defined for rational numbers whose value is the minimum of the numerator and denominator when the fraction is in lowest terms, this seems way too specialized to me to have any kind of standardized special name, although some authors may have used their own terminology.

Comment: This is called the [(naive multiplicative) height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_function) of a rational number (in Diophantine geometry). But I don't think this name is "standard" enough to use it without definition elsewhere.